# Elasticsearch Nest filter query with multiple terms

Tags: c#, linq, elasticsearch, nest

I am using Nest 7.x and Elasticsearch 7.x.

I need to add a filter while searching for a documents.
Here I have a list to use for filter,

```
nameList = [
        "aaa",
        "abc/ bbb" 
        ];
```

this is the filter,

```
fq => fq.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.Name).Terms(nameList))
```

The filter works fine for single word - "aaa", but it did not work while passing "abc  /  bbb". I think it is due to multiwords.  Cause, when I tried searching my documents using just abc or bbb, it got all the results with "aaa" and "abc/ bbb".

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: So, it is an union filter, the results with both aaa and abc / bbb should comes back.

Comment: are you looking for a match on the litteral value `abc / bbb`, spaces and all ?

Comment: mike b, yes.  in my case, f.Name will be  something like - "abc / bbb" , "food / drinks". It is  already saved in the elasticsearch.